# Sonarqube reported issue not valid

Tags: null, sonarqube

I've found a case of a sonarqube reported issue on which I disagree.

```java
    [2] String[] originalBeanNames = [1] applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(requiredType);
    if ([3] originalBeanNames == null || originalBeanNames.length != 1) {
        ...
    }
```

Sonarqube says:

1. 'getBeanNamesForType()' can return not null.
2. Implies 'originalBeanNames' can be not null.
3. Expression is always false.

[Sonarqube original issue]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N5Ip.png

In my opinion, this is wrong: why (2) implies that "`originalBeanNames`" cannot be null?

It could be not null but it could also be null, depending on the result of the "`applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(...)`" invocation.
Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This SonarQube warning is reasonable. From Javadoc:

```
 /**
 ...<omitted>...
 * @return the names of beans (or objects created by FactoryBeans) matching
 * the given object type (including subclasses), or an empty array if none
 ...<omitted>...
 */
String[] getBeanNamesForType(@Nullable Class<?> type);
```

Note

> or an empty array if none

It claims that this method will never return null

Comment: Yes, the javadoc states this... but this is only a comment, how can sonarqube know this? Maybe I'll do some tests to verify if this behavior is the same using a new method, created in my code, instead of "getBeanNamesForType".

Comment: I made these tests: I created a new method, in the same class, always returning a non-null value, and I invoked it. Sonarqube correctly reports the issue, because it can inspect the new method content, verifying that a null value cannot be returned.
If I move that new method in another class, sonarqube cannot go that deep, and the issue is not reported. This is reasonable.

So, I still don't understand the different behavior in original code. Maybe, since the invocation to that Spring method is very common, in some way sonarqube has 'whitelisted' it?

Comment: SonarQube parses null-related annotations to know if something can or cannot be null. As for Spring, `org.springframework.context` package is annotated as `@NonNullApi` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNullApi.html), meaning that _parameters and return values are to be considered as non-nullable by default_.

Comment: Thank you Raspy, THIS is the answer I was searching. If you write it as answer, I will accept it.